# Creating a drag and drop system with a trash can to remove object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I'm having trouble creating a a script the allows for a gameobject to be dropped onto a trash area of the screen thereby destroying the gameobject. Where am I going wrong in the onDrop function? Basically I'm trying to say that when a GameObject gets dropped onto the trash can it becomes a child of the trash can and once it's a child it gets destroyed. Does this logic make sense?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class DropZone : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler 
    {
        public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            if(eventData.pointerDrag == null)
                return;

            DragHandling dragHandling = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragHandling>();

            if(dragHandling != null)
            {
                dragHandling.placeholderParent = this.transform;        // change parent based on drop zone
            } 
        }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(eventData.pointerDrag == null)
            return;

        DragHandling dragHandling = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragHandling>();
        if(dragHandling != null && dragHandling.placeholderParent == this.transform)
        {
            dragHandling.placeholderParent = dragHandling.parentToReturnTo;     // change parent based on drop zone
        } 
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(eventData.pointerDrag.name + " was dropped on " + gameObject.name);

        DragHandling dragHandling = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragHandling>();

        if(dragHandling != null)
        {
            dragHandling.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;     // change parent based on drop zone
        }  

        if (this.transform.parent.gameObject == dragHandling.trashCan) 
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the script I'm referencing to get my variables:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DragHandling : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public Transform placeholderParent = null;
    public Transform parentToReturnTo = null;

    GameObject placeholder = null;

    public GameObject trashCan;
    public Transform trashCanTrans;
    public GameObject partsPanel;
    public Transform partsPanelTrans;
    public GameObject buildBoard;
    public GameObject dragLayer;

    void Awake ()
    {
        dragLayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DragLayer");
        buildBoard = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Board");
        partsPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Parts");
        trashCan = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Trash");

        partsPanelTrans = partsPanel.transform;
        // trashCanTrans = trashCan.transform;
    }

    #region IPointerClickHandler implementation

    public void OnPointerClick (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if(this.transform.parent.gameObject == buildBoard)
        {
            this.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

    public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // this.transform.SetAsLastSibling();

        // create placeholder gap and hold correct position in layout
        placeholder = new GameObject();
        placeholder.transform.SetParent(this.transform.parent);
        placeholder.transform.SetSiblingIndex(this.transform.GetSiblingIndex());

        LayoutElement le = placeholder.AddComponent<LayoutElement>();               // add layout element

        le.preferredWidth = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredWidth;      
        le.preferredHeight = this.GetComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredHeight;
        le.flexibleWidth = 0;
        le.flexibleHeight = 0;

        parentToReturnTo = this.transform.parent;                   // store current parent location
        placeholderParent = parentToReturnTo;                       // set placeholder gameobject transform

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;         // turn off image raycasting when dragging image in order to see what's behind the image            
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDragHandler implementation

    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.transform.position = eventData.position;               // set object coordinates to mouse coordinates
        this.transform.SetParent(dragLayer.transform);              // pop object to draglayer to move between dropzones
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.transform.SetParent(parentToReturnTo);                                 // Snaps object back to orginal parent if dropped outside of a dropzone
        this.transform.SetSiblingIndex(placeholder.transform.GetSiblingIndex());    // Returns card back to placeholder location

        GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;                          // turn on Raycast blocking

        Destroy(placeholder);                                                       // kill the placeholder if object hits a drop zone or returns to parts panel
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Okay, so I made a few changes and now when I drag the gameobject onto the trashcan it gets destroyed but so does the trashcan. I've been trying to get it to work, but still no luck. Here's what I have now, but it's still not working correctly.

public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(eventData.pointerDrag.name + " was dropped on " + gameObject.name);

```
    DragHandling dragHandling = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragHandling>();

    if(dragHandling != null)
    {
        dragHandling.parentToReturnTo = this.transform;     // change parent based on drop zone

        if (this.transform.gameObject == dragHandling.trashCan) 
        {
            Debug.Log("You've dragged something into the trash!");

            Destroy(this.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: If all the previous variable have correct expected value, I would say it's the Destroy() function, does all the previous vars have the value you expect them to have ?

Comment: I think so...Here's the script variables I'm referencing. Just added the other script to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honnestly i don't think you should put "this" into the destroy function, see one asking the question directly : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19223/is-destroygameobject-the-same-as-destroythis.html

You'r trying to destroy the drop zone instead of destroying the gameObject. Destroy only the gameObject and everything should be ok.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. How do I identify the GameObject I'm trying to kill in the destroy function? Destroy(gameObject) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well I'm not sure in that case, it's hard to say, but quickly, i'd say it's this.transform.parent.gameObject   your trying to destroy. Ho and don't forget to accept the answer if it work, it migth help other people

Comment: Hey Antoine, I just posted back up in the original post what's going on now with that change.

Comment: ok so now when destroying the gameObject, it also destroy the trash can, is that the new problem ?

Comment: Yes. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: posted new answer acording to that fact

Comment: It's destroying the parent along with the child.

Answer (score 1):

If the trash can destroy itself along with the game object, do not make that object be a child of the trash can. What probably happens here is that destroy() function wants to also destroy the parents of the object in order to maintain coherence in the datas.

Comment: What would something like that look like in code? If GameObject gets dropped onto other GameObject, destroy it.

Comment: In fact, it's pretty confusing, don't give up ! i'll be there tomorow.